# How to fix undefined error when using Alan AI with React and News API?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, alan

I am trying to use Alan AI with React to fetch news headlines from the News API. I have written a dialog script in Alan AI Studio that uses the fetch() method to make a GET request to the News API and display the articles in cards. However, when I test my dialog command in the Debugging Chat or Test View, I get an undefined error in the console.log.

Code: Here is my dialog script in Alan AI Studio:

```
    useEffect(()=> {
        alanBtn({
            key: alanKey,
            onCommand: ({ command, articles })=> {
                if(command === "newHeadlines") {
                    console.log(articles);
                }
               
            }}
        )
    } , [])
```

Here is my React code that uses alanBtn() to create an Alan button and handle the onCommand function:

```
const API_KEY = "ef1dc56abdf14f858a52b61ada48a4ac"
let savedArticles = [];
// News by Source
intent('Give me the news from $(source* (.*))', (p) => {
    let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
    
    if(p.source.value) {
        p.source.value=p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-");
        NEWS_API_URL = `${NEWS_API_URL}?sources=${p.source.value}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`
    }

    api.request(NEWS_API_URL, {headers: {"user-agent": 'user agent' }}, (error, response, body) => {
        const { totalResults, articles } = JSON.parse(body);

        if(totalResults == 0) {
            p.play('Sorry, please try searching for news from a different source');
            return;
        }

        savedArticles = articles;

        p.play({ command: 'newHeadlines', articles });
        p.play(`Here are (latest|recent) ${p.source.value} news.`);

        p.play('Would you like me to read the headlines?');

    });
})
```

I get an undefined error in the console.log, Can anyone please help me fix this issue? Thank you very much.

Expected result: I expect to see the news headlines from the News API in the console.log

Actual result: I get an undefined error in the console.log

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the API request. You can't use Source and Country in the same api Request--> check the News Api Documentation. Either remove source and keep the the Country or Vise Versa. I hope this helps.

// News by Source
intent('Give me the news from $(source* (.*))', (p) => {
let NEWS_API_URL = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=${API_KEY}`;
// Country and source can not go together in the same Api CALL
if(p.source.value) {
NEWS_API_URL = `${NEWS_API_URL}&sources=${p.source.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join('-')}`
}

```
api.axios.get(NEWS_API_URL).then((response)=>{
    let { articles } = response.data;
    
    if(!articles.length) {
        p.play('Sorry, please try searching for news from a different source');
        return;
    }
    
    savedArticles = articles;
    
    p.play({ command: 'newHeadlines', articles });
    p.play(`Here are the (latest|recent) ${p.source.value}.`);

    p.play('Would you like me to read the headlines?');
    p.then(confirmation);
});
```

})